# Xbee S2 mesh network (API) with sensors on Arduino-s

Tags: api, arduino, sensors, arduino-uno, xbee

I'm working on a project with Xbee-s (S2) and Arduino UNO-s. My plan is to create a mesh sensor network from 5 radios (it would be a home measuring system):  1 coordinator (API) mode  with Arduino connected to PC (only reciving and processing data), 1 (or 2) router in AT mode, and 2 (or 3) end devices with Arduinos connected them,  1 sensor connected to each Arduinos.(I have an LM-35, BMP-180 and DHT-11).
I want to process the data from the sensors with the Arduino-s and wrap these data into Xbee packets which the Xbee-s connected to the Arduinos will send to the coordinator ( through router node in AT- mode, if needed), where the Arduino connected to that coordinator receive these packets from the coordinator, sort out these packets and read out from each of packets the sensor readings values. Then converts these values for strings and print them on the serial monitor on PC (without getting them mixed). For example like this:

"Measured value from E1:
Temperature: °C
Humidity: % "

"Measured value from E2:
Temperature: °C "

"Measured value from E3:
 Air pressure:  Pa "

My summary question : is this concept doable in this way? I'm only willing to print on the serial monitor on PC the values.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely possible.  The "AT mode" firmware supports "transparent serial" mode where anything the host sends out the serial port will be relayed to a fixed node on the network (often the coordinator).  If the coordinator is running in API mode, the data will come in frames with a header that identifies the source.

The coordinator can use API frames to direct any data to the remote nodes with AT firmware, and the payload will come out on the serial port -- no headers or footers to process.